# How to successfully modify in PHP the DOM of the Document of a CSS class in my case?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I am trying to modify (replace) with `DomDocument` the attribute of the `new` CSS class of the `a` tag (*framed on the following screenshot in **green***) which I have checked well with the  `function stripos` and try to replace its `href` attribute (*i.e. replace the `href` attribute of the `a` tag with `new` CSS class*) with `str_ireplace`:

[image]

My following PHP Code looks correct **but doesn't work at all:**

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$parser = new DOMDocument();
$parser->loadHTMLFile("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alibaba_Group");
$get_a_tags = $parser->getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach ($get_a_tags as $get_a_tag) {
                if (stripos($get_a_tag->getAttribute('class'), "new") !== false) {
                    $get_href_in_a_infobox = $get_a_tag->getAttribute('href');
                    $term = $get_a_tag->nodeValue;
                    $urlSearch = BASE_PATH."search.php?term=$term&type=sites";
                    // var_dump($urlSearch."<br><br>");
                    $wikipediaInfoboxTable = str_ireplace($get_href_in_a_infobox, $urlSearch, $wikipediaInfoboxTable);
                }
            }
```

So, how to succeed in replacing the value of the `href` attribute of all the `a` tags having the `new` CSS class by the value of the `$urlSearch` variable knowing that `$wikipediaInfoboxTable` contains the entire table of the infobox in which I would like to make my replacement ???

Thank you please help me.

Comment: Can you write the Title in English as well please

Comment: It's Done. I really need help.

Comment: Your code works for me. What error do you get? Where does `$wikipediaInfoboxTable` get set?

Comment: `$wikipediaInfoboxTable` is a string, right? If it's a PHP DOMElement, it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `DomDocument` you can try using the `setAttribute` method to change the `href` value:

```
foreach ($get_a_tags as $get_a_tag) {
    //...
    $get_a_tag->setAttribute('href', $urlSearch);
}
$newHtml = $parser->saveHTML();
```